# Adding columns of strings (row-wise) in a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a data frame with columns that are all strings. There are occasional `NA`'s as well. I want to add all the columns into one vector row-by-row so that I can get only the unique strings in the entire data frame. Given a sample data like this:

```
        L1     L2    L3    L4
1      bed bicyle  <NA>  bird
2     <NA>   road   cat dance
3      cat   rock table   bed
4 mountain    bed clock  <NA>
```

Then I want something like this:

```
                                                     Total
1 bed bicyle bird road cat dance rock table mountain clock
```

I can obviously do this with a loop, but I am trying to figure out an apply or plyr type solution (which is more `R`-like). So far I can get a list of arrays but I then get stuck trying to add those arrays together. Is my approach even correct? Any help is appreciated.

```
df <- data.frame(L1 = c("bed", NA, "cat", "mountain"), 
                 L2 = c("bicyle", "road", "rock", "bed"), 
                 L3 = c(NA, "cat", "table", "clock"), 
                 L4 = c("bird", "dance", "bed", NA))
df <- lapply(df, unique)
```

Comment: `na.omit(unique(unlist(lapply(t(df), as.character))))`

Comment: Thanks; I forgot about the unlist method..

Comment: In case someone was not looking for unique values then `as.character(na.omit(unlist(df)))` You can also use `unique()` on this to get unique values.

Comment: @d.b Was wondering why you need `t(df)`. Just a side question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
unique(as.vector(t(df)))
```

Or, whitout `NAs`:

```
unique(na.omit(as.vector(t(df))))
```

Comment: This is a clever solution! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to accomplish your task:

```
require(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(L1 = c("bed", NA, "cat", "mountain"), 
                 L2 = c("bicyle", "road", "rock", "bed"), 
                 L3 = c(NA, "cat", "table", "clock"), 
                 L4 = c("bird", "dance", "bed", NA), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df <- df %>% unlist() %>% na.omit() %>% unique()
```

Output:

```
 [1] "bed"      "cat"      "mountain" "bicyle"   "road"     "rock"     "table"    "clock"    "bird"     "dance"
```

Comment: `dplyr` is your favorite package ;)

Comment: Ha! I think it's easier for people new to R to learn to do basic things.

Comment: In my head I was envisioning something like this, but had no idea where to start.. thanks!